# RVM remove all rubies and all corresponding gemsets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

How to remove all rubies and their corresponding gemsets. Also is it possible that all source file for rubies and gems are also removed.

I tried `rvm implode`

It seems that it removed rvm also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rvm remove all` should do this for you.

The alternative is to just reinstall `rvm` after an implode and that usually doesn't take too long.

Comment: you are probably right, took me less than 10 mins to be up and running again.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure what you want is:

```
rvm remove all --archive --gems
```

This will remove all rubies, all of the download archive and all associated gemsets. If you don't include the flag, all rubies will be removed but all of the installed gems will stick around in your `~/.rvm/gems/`. For me this was about 1.62Gb of gems I don't want left lying around.

Hope this helps!